# Device-independent QKD - truly achieving security?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

The issue of security of QKD is, as commonly known, the practical implementation. I know that it is possible to hack commercial quantum crypto systems as it was done e.g. by the Quantum Hacking Lab. I found out that Device-independent QKD is an attempt to tackle these issues. In [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-02307-4), the authors claim that "instead of trying to come up with a “patch” each time an
imperfection in the device is detected, DI protocols allow us to
break the cycle of attacks and countermeasures."

However, from my (naive) perspective, this seems to be a promise that cannot necessarily be kept. I'm aware that DIQKD can safe us from malicious devices (when the manufacturer is an eavesdropper), but this does not imply that an eavesdropper outside the lab could possibly somehow enter Alice's and Bob's devices (with some trojan horse attack that is customized to the used devices) and gain information about the key somehow without destroying the entanglement, as it was already done for device-dependent QKD. It seems unimaginable to me that these DIQKD security proofs do really hold independently of the regarded practical implementation. Maybe this suspicion only arises due to my lack of understanding/knowledge of the advances of DIQKD compared to usual QKD (because any QKD protocol is based on entanglement, not only DIQKD) - I'd be grateful for clarification.